# Make a form with two buttons from a php file to choose an action

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, mysqli

i have the following html:

```
<body onload="showcontent()"> <!-- onload optional -->
        <div id="content"><img src="loading.gif"></div> <!-- leave img out if not onload -->
    </body>
```

I also have the following script:

function showcontent(){

```
  if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
  }

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 1) {
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = "<img src='loading.gif' />";
    }
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    } 
  }

  xmlhttp.open('GET', 'elsevier.php', true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  xmlhttp.send(null);

}
```

In elsevier.php I want when the rows of a table exceed 500 two buttons to be displayed, telling me whether to continue or cancel. If I put this code in the .php file nothing happens..... (except that two buttons appear).

```
if(mysqli_errno($con)==1062){
                    @$q55="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM testarticles";
                    $result55 = mysqli_query($con, $q55);
                    $row = $result55->fetch_row();
                    echo '#: ', $row[0].'<br>';

                    if($row[0]>=500&&$answer==false){
                        echo '<form action="" method="GET">';
                        echo "<label>Do you want to continue or cancel?</label>";
                        echo '<input type="button" id="but1" name="but1" value="Continue">';
                        echo '<input type="button" id="but2" name="but2" value="Cancel">';
                        echo '</form>';

                        //sleep(2);

                        if(isset($_GET["but1"])){
                           $answer=true;
                           break;
                         }
                         elseif(isset($_GET["but2"])){
                           @$q56="DELETE * FROM journal, volume, issue, articles, testarticles WHERE import_time=$unixtimestamp";
                           $result56 = mysqli_query($con, $q56);
                           exit;
                         }
                    }
```

I want in this step the execution of the php script to stop and to display me the two buttons to choose from. If i press continue i want the script to execute from where it was stopped.

Has anybody any idea?? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think that this cannot be done with php.. Maybe I'm wrong.. You can do it by adding the results to a session variable and then to continue adding from db from the last item in that session var

Comment: if it can be done in some other way have you anything in mind? Thanks.

Comment: could you give me an example,please? thanks.

Comment: No.. sorry.. I think that using session vars is the single idea which I have in mind right now..

Comment: i mean if you can give me an example code with that session var..

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();

if(mysqli_errno($con)==1062){ 

                $where = isset($_SESSION['last_id']) ? " WHERE id > '" . $_SESSION['last_id'] . "'" : "";
                if(isset($_SESSION['last_id']))
                    unset($_SESSION['last_id']);

                @$q55="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM testarticles$where ORDER BY id"; 
                $result55 = mysqli_query($con, $q55); 
                $row = $result55->fetch_row(); 
                echo '#: ', $row[0].'<br>'; 

                if($row[0] >= 500 && $answer == false){

                    $_SESSION['last_id'] = $row['id'];

                    echo "<label>Do you want to continue or cancel?</label>"; 
                    echo '<input type="button" id="but1" name="but1" value="Continue" onclick="showcontent(true)" />'; 
                    echo '<input type="button" id="but2" name="but2" value="Cancel">'; 

                    //sleep(2); 

                    if(isset($_GET["but1"])){ 
                       $answer=true; 
                       break; 
                     } 
                     elseif(isset($_GET["but2"])){ 
                       @$q56="DELETE * FROM journal, volume, issue, articles, testarticles WHERE import_time=$unixtimestamp"; 
                       $result56 = mysqli_query($con, $q56); 
                       exit; 
                     } 
                }
```

You have to modify also the showcontent function because when you press the continue button the content retrieved should be appended and not replaced

```
function showcontent(){
  if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {           
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();           
  } else {           
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');           
  }           

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {           
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 1 && !update) {           
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = "<img src='loading.gif' />";           
    }           
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      if(update)
        alert("this is an update and I should append data, not to replace the div content");
      else {       
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;           
        //this is the first call of the function so the content of the div will be replaced
      }
    }            
  }           

  xmlhttp.open('GET', 'elsevier.php', true);           
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');           
  xmlhttp.send(null);           

}
```

HTML Code:

```
<body onload="showcontent(false)"> <!-- onload optional -->              
   <div id="content"><img src="loading.gif"></div> <!-- leave img out if not onload -->              
</body>
```

Note that this is not a verified code so you should modify it

Comment: i didn't understand exactly this line: $where = isset($_SESSION['last_id']) ? " WHERE id > '" . $_SESSION['last_id'] . "'" : "";

Comment: this is equivalent with: `if(isset($_SESSION['last_id'])) $where = "where..."; else $where = "";`. That's the short way of using if else statements

Comment: oh yes right... and the id inside row[]? where do you declare it? i ran it.. the continue button works, but the cancel doesn't delete anything....

Comment: the id inside row should be the DB Field ID which is primary key. For deleting content you should do another javascript function like `function deleteContent() { document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = ''; }` and the button should be like `echo '<input type="button" id="but2" name="but2" value="Cancel" onclick="deleteContent()" />';`

Comment: i mean how to delete the contents of the db table.. anyway it's clear now! thanks again!!

Answer (score -1):

use '**`echo`**' followed by the <*html code*> for creating a button. You will be done.

Comment: While adding answers to old questions is sometimes useful, usually it is not.  Working on newer questions is generally more useful and rewarding.